# Add lines along axes in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axis

I have such a piece of code for generating two plots in `jupyter notebook`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))

x = np.arange(10)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, x)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x, x)
```

[image]

How can I add black lines that go along axes?

Like this one:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the `darkgrid` theme of seaborn.
You want to use to `tick` style instead.

```
sns.set_style("ticks")
```

See [Controlling figure aesthetics](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following rcParams by adding the following lines to the code:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.left'] =  True
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.bottom'] =  True
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] =  True
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] =  True
```

Comment: The fact is that the offline Python interpretor(not of the Jupyter notebook) shows spines by default. So doing it offline might be an option too.